# *FIXED* Good with PHP arrays? HELP!

Tags: php, arrays, merge, associative

I know there are a lot of smart people, so prove me right!

I want to combine arrays where similar named keys merge together to form a single array. See example:

```
[Bob] => Array
(
    [BobsDetails] => Array
    (
       [Title] => Mr
    )
)

[Bob] => Array
(
    [BobsDetails] => Array
    (
         [Surname] => Smith
     )
)
```

**How do I end up with ONE array that looks like:**

```
[Bob] => Array
(
    [BobsDetails] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Mr
            [Surname] => Smith
        )
)
```

Thanks in advance guys

PS I dont think it is as simple as array_merge... ;(

*EDIT* Made it easier to read

*EDIT* Sorted. Thanks for the help. array_merge_recursive worked

Comment: I think renaming your question to better identify the content would be a good idea - especially for people searching the archives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you just have to array merge $array['Basic'] instead of just $array;

Actually, if you use array_merge_recursive() on $array it will work. (Check for recursive versions of common functions for multi-dimensional arrays)

Comment: So yeah, it is as simple as array_merge(). :P

Comment: Thanks my love.

And Chaacha102: Goddamn you.